# How to make a dynamic matrix inside a loop in Scilab?

Tags: matrix, scilab

I have a dynamic 3d-matrix inside a for loop in Scilab wherein the values are added to the matrix every iteration as shown in the code snippet below. My problem is, everytime I open Scilab and run my code, the line after the for loop will generate an error that says, 'Submatrix incorrectly defined'.

I tried deleting the '(ii,:,:)', there's no error but the output is not what I intended it to be. I added it again and the code worked just fine. When I closed Scilab, opened it, and ran it again, the error appeared again. Can somebody tell me what's wrong? Or is there another way to make a dynamic matrix inside a for loop?

```
    for ii = 1:N
        Fn(ii,:,:) = repmat((1./VAL(ii)),[a b c]).*POP(ii,:,:);
        Fd(ii,:,:) = repmat((1./VAL(ii)),[a b c]);
    end
```

Comment: Please give self-contained code, what are `POP,val,a,b,c` ?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, before your loop you should initialize first `Fn` and `Fd` to their known maximum size. However there seems to be a size mismatch, in the two inner lines of your loop, unless that `a` is equal to 1.